# Evitar ejecución de assert hasta recibir una respuesta

Tags: nodejs, mocha, test, tdd

Estoy creando una prueba unitaria, dicha prueba consta de utilizar la API de twitter para obtener datos de cualquier perfil (Nombre, cantidad de tweets, seguidores, fecha de registro, etc). La cuestión es que estoy utilizando la librería Mocha para esta tarea, pero me encuentro con el problema, de que al realizar la ejecución del assert, la petición de twitter tarda más de 2 segundos (El tiempo por defecto de Mocha para el timeout), por tanto mi prueba siempre falla.

Alguien podría darme una mano? Qué debería hacer, para que la comparación del assert se ejecute después de recibir todos los de la petición a twitter?

Calculadora.js

```
class Calculadora {
    verificarUsername(a) {
        if (a) {
            var nombre;
            var Twitter = require('twitter');
            var client = new Twitter({
              consumer_key: 'XSpj4nEB5IOLgIvyZXiDAhBLt',
              consumer_secret: 'dPjYUTih6n0ynt1y9C7bE0g0gyx6KSJgrGTeDEa3yH5flsdJPL',
              access_token_key: '900532686-4sOwDfOFZm1fKmtZZhSMPH04REXMjqnugTOn3o1j',
              access_token_secret: 'ghNtHt7VyjwNHXvXnZM5hFKaDH62bX7LEFqUBZ9SSb5Lg'
            });

            client.get('users/show', {screen_name: a}, function(error, response) {
              if(error) throw error;
              if(response.name) {
                nombre = true
              } else {
                nombre = false
              };
              console.log(` 
                Nombre: '${response.name}'
                ID: ${response.id_str}
                Localidad: ${response.location}
                Descripción del perfil: ${response.description}
                Seguidores: ${response.followers_count}
                Sigue a: ${response.friends_count}
                Perfil creado el: ${response.created_at}\n`);
            });
            return nombre;
        }


    }
}

module.exports = Calculadora;
```

Prueba.js

```
var assert = require('assert');
var Calculadora = require('../calculadora.js');

describe('Pruebas de perfil de Twitter', function() {
    this.timeout(5000);
    var c = new Calculadora();
    it('Verifica si se le pasó un username válido', function(done) {

        assert.equal(c.verificarUsername('pedrofumero'),true, 'El username proporcionado no es válido');
        done()
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

yo haría uso de los métodos callback. La idea es muy sencilla, el método "verificaUsername" no retorna un valor, sino que llama a una función callback que será pasada por parámetro. Para que sea así, primero se debería cambiar dicho método, para que funcione de esa manera:

```js
class Calculadora {
    verificarUsername(a,cbFunction) {
        if (a != undefined && cbFunction != undefined) {
            var nombre;
            var Twitter = require('twitter');
            var client = new Twitter({
              consumer_key: 'XSpj4nEB5IOLgIvyZXiDAhBLt',
              consumer_secret: 'dPjYUTih6n0ynt1y9C7bE0g0gyx6KSJgrGTeDEa3yH5flsdJPL',
              access_token_key: '900532686-4sOwDfOFZm1fKmtZZhSMPH04REXMjqnugTOn3o1j',
              access_token_secret: 'ghNtHt7VyjwNHXvXnZM5hFKaDH62bX7LEFqUBZ9SSb5Lg'
            });

            client.get('users/show', {screen_name: a}, function(error, response) {
              if(error) throw error;
              if(response.name) {
                nombre = true
              } else {
                nombre = false
              };
              console.log(` 
                Nombre: '${response.name}'
                ID: ${response.id_str}
                Localidad: ${response.location}
                Descripción del perfil: ${response.description}
                Seguidores: ${response.followers_count}
                Sigue a: ${response.friends_count}
                Perfil creado el: ${response.created_at}\n`);
            });
            cbFunction(nombre);
        }


    }
}

module.exports = Calculadora;
```

Luego se tiene que cambiar la prueba unitaria, para asegurar que el assert sea lo que se ejecuta en la función de callback, que está inmediatamente despues de "pedrofumero".:

```js
var assert = require('assert');
var Calculadora = require('../calculadora.js');

describe('Pruebas de perfil de Twitter', function() {
    this.timeout(5000);
    var c = new Calculadora();
    it('Verifica si se le pasó un username válido', function(done) {
        c.verificarUsername('pedrofumero', function(result) {
            assert.equal(result, true, 'El username proporcionado es válido');
            done();
        })

    })
})
```

De esta forma hacemos que la función que se pasa por parámetro se ejecute solo cuando se obtenga la respuesta desde Twitter. Es un concepto bastante básico, que te va a servir mucho a la hora de programar en NodeJS.

PD: Asegurate de hacer bien los asserts, si no te vas a volver loco, estabas haciendo esto:

```js
 assert.equal(c.verificarUsername('pedrofumero'),true, 'El username proporcionado no es válido');
```

Y eso significa "Asegura que es igual: el resultado de c.verificarUsername('pedrofumero') y el valor booleano true, y de ser así, muestra el mensaje "El username proporcionado no es válido". Si te das cuenta, el mensaje que se muestra es totalmente lo contrario a lo que se está buscando con el assert.

No he podido probar la respuesta porque no me encuentro en mi PC, pero debería funcionar o al menos servirte para saber que tienes que hacer en este caso.